# What does "se me nubló el semblante" mean in Spanish?

Tags: modismos

Google translate says:

> He clouded the face

But I'm sure that's not the case. I think it's something someone feels when they feel pity(?) or kind of when someone stop having bad feelings for someone else, right?

I also tried with Linguee, but didn't' help much either.

http://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=nubl%C3%B3+el+semblante

Like a heartwarming feeling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, it's a *metaphor*. Actually, it's a fairly common one, so much that RAE even includes it:

> [Nublar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qh2z67V):
>   6. tr. Hacer que el semblante exprese tristeza o inquietud. *La indecisión y el temor nublaron su rostro.* U. t. c. prnl.

Translation: to make someone's countenance express sadness or worry. RAE's abbreviations are slightly cryptical, but *u. t. c. prnl* means "usado también como verbo pronominal" (also used as a pronominal verb; that is, "nublarse").

The idea is basically that when clouds cover the sky, the atmosphere becomes suddenly gloomy and kind of uneasy. Similarly, someone can "cloud" their face if they change their expression suddenly, causing in the observer the same feeling as though clouds had covered the sky. Of course, as with many other metaphors, there's more than one possible interpretation. Even though the meaning of this expression is quite clear and standard, why this expression means what it means is debatable, so that's up to the reader.

Edit: As per @rsanchez's comment, the equivalent English expression would be [*cloud over*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cloud-over).

Comment: The way the metaphor works is what I wasn't sure about. "the atmosphere becomes suddenly gloomy and kind of uneasy. Similarly, someone can "cloud" their face if they change their expression" explains it perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Jpablobr: You're welcome, I'm glad it's been helpful!

Comment: The same expression exists in English http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cloud-over

Comment: @rsanchez Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: @rsanchez Awesome, I didn't know either!